# Lua - Zoom buttons - Help me

Tags: android, lua, zooming, coronasdk

So I'm working on piano app in Corona SDK (I'd like to say that I'm still a newbie to it). Basically the app layout is 'static' as I call it (there's no any scrollview etc.). Keyboard is situated on top of the screen and it covers like 1/5 of whole background, so every key is tiny, unplayable. And I don't know how to make zoom function containing buttons feature. If out there would be 2 buttons; one with '+' and one with '-', situated in bottom's 2 corners. I want them to don't change their size and position while zooming. Then when it's zoomed, no matter how deep, app work would be easily scrollable. I'd love the both, zooming and scrolling to be smooth, so you were be able to individually select your playing setup in your own preference. Can you help me and give some code suggestions, please? (as I said before I'm new..)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to look into [group programming guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/group.html). As I understand you need to place Keyboard in separate group and use xScale/yScale properties to zoom it.

```
--setup keyboard
keyboardGroup = display.newGroup()
sceneGroup:insert(keyboardGroup) -- sceneGroup may have different name in your code
--insert keys example
keyboardGroup:insert(yourKeyObject)
```

Zoom function:

```
function setZoom(xValue, yValue)
  keyboardGroup.xScale = xValue
  keyboardGroup.yScale = yValue
end
```

Zoom buttons should be placed in another display group, so they will not be affected by scaling

Comment: Im assuming all keys should be stacked in some kind of table. What if I have done each key by individual?

Comment: @rd119 if  each key is a separate display object you need to call `keyboardGroup:insert(keyHere)` for each object, so they will scale at once

Comment: It looks like everything must have its own separate groups. My point is to have everything (background, keyboard etc.) except zoom button as one valid thing that zooms exactly like photo on your mobile by pinch zooming. Is there any other way to do that?